# Error while auto-deploying angular app from bit bucket to heroku

Tags: heroku, bitbucket, angular7

I'm trying to auto deploy angular app to heroku from bitbucket when we push to master branch.Creates build correctly but while deploying it throws error.
this is my .yml file

```
image: node:10.15.3

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - node
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - npm install
          - npm test
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: Build app
          script:
            - npm install
            - npm install -g @angular/cli
            - ng build --prod --build-optimizer --progress=false
          artifacts: 
             - file-systme.tgz
      - step:
         name: Deploy to production
         deployment: production
         script:
           - pipe: atlassian/heroku-deploy:1.1.0
             variables:
               HEROKU_API_KEY: '**'
               HEROKU_APP_NAME: 'xyz'
               ZIP_FILE: 'file-systme.tgz'
```

please help
EDIT:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: file-systme.tgz

Comment: Please provide the error you are getting

Comment: @DenisCornehl Edited my question

Comment: Did you find the solution to that?